# Phonegap - Access data offline from database

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql, lawnchair

I have mutiple tables on my server side which I need to fetch data from and store it on my client side *Phonegap* so it can be accessed offline.

I found [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) but I can't find enough documentation how to save and update mutiple tables.

There is also [WebSQL](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) but I believe it's deprecated. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

How can new data get fetched/ current data gets updated only when the device gets connected online?! In other words, any operation will be done on the data saved on the device.

Comment: Cordova database plugin? [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple SQLite plugins, I've used the one from Brodysoft with success:
https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

<s>There are no events for when a device goes online/offline.</s> There's a plugin for network connectivity events (cordova-plugin-network-information). You can also sync when the app launches, or have a "sync now" button/gesture so the user can sync on demand.

Comment: You don't need any plugin for a database since you can just still use WebSQL.

Comment: WebSQL is deprecated and support may be dropped.  It's also not supported on all the platforms that Cordova targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/):

> PouchDB is an open-source JavaScript database inspired by Apache
>   CouchDB that is designed to run well within the browser.

The documentation there is really good and it works pretty well.

You can use it to replicate/sync (bidirectional) your local database with a remote [one](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#sync).

You can always disable the replication and managed it yourself.

It can be used with different [adapters](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html):

- LocalStorage
- IndexedDB
- WebSQL

It can be used with SQLite plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap.

Nic Raboy created a really nice video tutorial about pouchdb on his youtube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erQMOUcAdXk).

If you want to activate a manual sync when your app goes online you can use the `cordova-plugin-network-information`:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

together with $`cordovaNetwork` plugin from [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/).
You could simply intercept the online event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){

});
```

and take actions.